# How to integrate Akka in standalone java application

Tags: akka

How to integrate *akka* in my simple standalone java project in eclipse
without using activator , sbt. 
I am trying with maven but it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/intro/getting-started.html

Akka is simply a just other jar-lib on your project classpath.